# transparent status bar with fitsSystemwindows toolbar pushed up

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

```
Android Studio 2.3 RC 1
```

I have created an app that uses a transparent status bar that works ok as the status bar is transparent. The problem is with my toolbar as it seems to get pushed up. I have been trying to solve this issue using fitsSystemWindows to true. However, this has not worked.

[image]

Just wondering if there is something I am doing wrong.

The layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.androidbox.busbymovies.movielist.MovieListViewImp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvMovieList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbMovieList"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My styles:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
```

And in my onCreate(..) in the main activity

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        final Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
 }
```

Comment: If you remove `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, since you have this element:

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

that you do actually want some kind of parallax when scrolling. So this tells me that what you really meant to do is use a CoordinatorLayout. So this isn't a direct answer to your question but it will work if you use this method and you can fix both problems. I'm taking into account the image I can see in your screenshot.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>        

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: I have updated my layout for using coordinatorLayout. However, the toolbar is still getting pushed up. I have updated the picture as well.

Comment: Try commenting out the flags for no limits. You don't need that to set the status bar translucent.